# use vbscript to unhide text and text input box upon certain condition

Tags: vbscript

Here's what I'm basically trying to do: I want to have a textbox and the text next to it hidden on my page unless a user selects certain options from another field. When the user selects those options then the text box should be visible, as well as the text right next to it telling the users what to input. So far after all of my research the only thing that appears to be capable of doing something like that is style.display, but have been unable to find anything close to the scenario I have.

Comment: This is an ASP page or a HTA application?

Comment: ASP page, should have specified that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You put an event handler whatever the other field is. Then you run script to unhide.

```
<tr><td width=25%><a ID="lnkP2" onclick="ShowPage3()" onmouseover="lnkP2.style.color='red'" onmouseout="lnkP2.style.color='black'" title="How to select files by file specifcation">Selecting</a></td>
```

In the script block in the header

```
Sub ShowPage3
    On Error Resume Next
    document.all.item("Page1",0).Style.Display="None"
End Sub
```

The div, for instance, with your controls

```
<div ID="Page1" class="content">
<h3>Welcome</h3>
</div>
```